How to handle scalability when sending DM with BotFramework
`I’ve exposed a route in my bot framework server to send direct messages (DMs) to users from my backend. I'm attaching images showing the exact code I'm using to send the messages.
My app is multi-tenant and has seen many installs, which has led to issues. Often, sending a message fails due to load, user not being found, or internal server errors.
Is there a better or simpler approach to sending direct messages to Microsoft Teams users in this scenario?
Here are the code images:
image 1
image 2
image 3`
